Why does $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{(\ln(n))^4}$ diverge
I was not sure what method to use so I decided to make a substitution to show that the p-series converges.
Let $m = \ln(n)$, thus $b_n=\frac{1}{m^4}$ and $\sum_2^\infty b_n$ converges since $p>1$.
I know $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ diverges but I'm not sure how to use this to show that the series diverges. Limit comparison test?

Use Cauchy condensation test. It's application gives the statement, $$ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^4} \text{ converges } \iff  \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^4(\ln{2})^4} \text{ converges }.$$
Thus, the given series diverges.

If you know that $\sum \frac 1{n }$ diverges you can use that $n \gt (\ln n)^4$ for large enough $n$ and the comparison test

Another alternative is that for large enough $n$, $\ln(n) \le n^{1/4}$ so that $\frac{1}{\ln^4(n)} \ge \frac{1}{n}$ the latter of which corresponds to the harmonic series which diverges, so your series diverges by direct comparison.
